# Insert iOS app in the public transportation list in Apple Maps

Tags: ios, apple-maps

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses google transit for giving the user directions using public transportations.

I would like to insert my app into the list that you can find in the apple maps, when you select public transportation directions.

But I can't find documentation on how to do this, any suggestion?

Comment: Well it is in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW7

Comment: I don't want to open Maps app from my app, I want the opposite, I want Maps app to launch my app. I want to insert my app in the list of the apps that supports public transportation directions in the Maps App..

Comment: Read the part of the documentation under `Registering as a Routing App`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show your app in the iOS Maps default application when you search for a public transportation you have to edit your app's PLIST file by adding this key:

```
MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes
```

and by setting it with your kind of transportation type, like "Bus".

Hope to help.